# How can I made the Run button in Replit work on this sequence?

Tags: replit, runcommand

So, I use code that can for some reason only be run in console using the command: 'python ./Ghost.py', and when I put that in the .replit file as the run command, it turns on and back off immediately. I want to know how to make the 'Run' button work, and what I need to put in the .replit file to do it. It used to work for some time, and then I updated the code and now it doesn't...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently if you use debugger, it works lol.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the file viewer click the 3 dots, then click Show Hidden files
In the `.replit` Edit the run string to look like `run="python ./Ghost.py"`

Answer (score 0):

make sure to show hidden files by clicking the 3 dots on the right of the create folder button then copy the following configs for each file

the .replit config for python3 :

```
run = "python3 main.py"

# The primary language of the repl. There can be others, though!
language = "python3"
entrypoint = "main.py"
# A list of globs that specify which files and directories should
# be hidden in the workspace.
hidden = ["venv", ".config", "**/__pycache__", "**/.mypy_cache", "**/*.pyc"]
modules = ["pyright-extended:v1-20230707-0c33b22"]

# Specifies which nix channel to use when building the environment.
[nix]
channel = "stable-22_11"

# The command to start the interpreter.
[interpreter]
  [interpreter.command]
  args = [
    "stderred",
    "--",
    "prybar-python310",
    "-q",
    "--ps1",
    "\u0001\u001b[33m\u0002\u0001\u001b[00m\u0002 ",
    "-i",
  ]
  env = { LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "$PYTHON_LD_LIBRARY_PATH" }

[env]
VIRTUAL_ENV = "${REPL_HOME}/venv"
PATH = "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin"
PYTHONPATH = "$PYTHONHOME/lib/python3.10:${VIRTUAL_ENV}/lib/python3.10/site-packages"
REPLIT_POETRY_PYPI_REPOSITORY = "https://package-proxy.replit.com/pypi/"
MPLBACKEND = "TkAgg"
POETRY_CACHE_DIR = "${REPL_HOME}/.cache/pypoetry"

# Enable unit tests. This is only supported for a few languages.
[unitTest]
language = "python3"

# Add a debugger!
[debugger]
support = true

  # How to start the debugger.
  [debugger.interactive]
  transport = "localhost:0"
  startCommand = ["dap-python", "main.py"]

    # How to communicate with the debugger.
    [debugger.interactive.integratedAdapter]
    dapTcpAddress = "localhost:0"

    # How to tell the debugger to start a debugging session.
    [debugger.interactive.initializeMessage]
    command = "initialize"
    type = "request"

      [debugger.interactive.initializeMessage.arguments]
      adapterID = "debugpy"
      clientID = "replit"
      clientName = "replit.com"
      columnsStartAt1 = true
      linesStartAt1 = true
      locale = "en-us"
      pathFormat = "path"
      supportsInvalidatedEvent = true
      supportsProgressReporting = true
      supportsRunInTerminalRequest = true
      supportsVariablePaging = true
      supportsVariableType = true

    # How to tell the debugger to start the debuggee application.
    [debugger.interactive.launchMessage]
    command = "attach"
    type = "request"

      [debugger.interactive.launchMessage.arguments]
      logging = {}

# Configures the packager.
[packager]
language = "python3"
ignoredPackages = ["unit_tests"]

  [packager.features]
  enabledForHosting = false
  # Enable searching packages from the sidebar.
  packageSearch = true
  # Enable guessing what packages are needed from the code.
  guessImports = true

# These are the files that need to be preserved when this 
# language template is used as the base language template
# for Python repos imported from GitHub
[gitHubImport]
requiredFiles = [".replit", "replit.nix", ".config", "venv"]

[deployment]
run = ["sh", "-c", "python3 main.py"]
```

the replix.nix config for python3 :

```
{ pkgs }: {
  deps = [
    pkgs.python310Full
    pkgs.replitPackages.prybar-python310
    pkgs.replitPackages.stderred
  ];
  env = {
    PYTHON_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = pkgs.lib.makeLibraryPath [
      # Needed for pandas / numpy
      pkgs.stdenv.cc.cc.lib
      pkgs.zlib
      # Needed for pygame
      pkgs.glib
      # Needed for matplotlib
      pkgs.xorg.libX11
    ];
    PYTHONHOME = "${pkgs.python310Full}";
    PYTHONBIN = "${pkgs.python310Full}/bin/python3.10";
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8";
    STDERREDBIN = "${pkgs.replitPackages.stderred}/bin/stderred";
    PRYBAR_PYTHON_BIN = "${pkgs.replitPackages.prybar-python310}/bin/prybar-python310";
  };
}
```